# HTML Automatic line-break doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, enter

I declared `width` and `margins` but somehow my lines didn't get wrapped with an automatic line-break.

[image]

edit:
I found the cause. It's because there are no spaces between words:

```
teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;teest&nbsp;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you mean `white-space:normal`?

Comment: What you want to do? Explain in detail.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) At least add a [short example](http://sscce.org) of your problem.

Comment: Why in the name of god does this have so many downvotes? Legit question. Happens to me too, and I can't remove the &nbsp because it's formatted from the stupid CMS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The element where text is should have css declaration:

```
div {
    display: block;
    width: 200px; /*based on how much width this div should have*/
}
```

and if it doesn't work try doing:

```
div { word-wrap: break-word }
```

Comment: word-wrap: break-word helped, but it breaking sometimes in half of words ;/

Comment: can you provide the css and html for not working part, or for the whole page? I'm quite sure it would help anybody to recognize the problem

Answer (score 5):

try this one by one, it must be helpful for some situation:

```
p{
    display: block; /* or inline-block, at least its a block element */
    width: 100px; /* or width is certain by parent element */
    height: auto; /* height cannot be defined */
    word-break: break-all; /*  */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* if you want to cut the complete word */
    white-space: normal; /* be sure its not 'nowrap'! ! ! :/ */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

another way to do it is by:

```
white-space: pre-wrap; // preserve whitespace, the text is wrapped
overflow-wrap: break-word; // text is wrapped, line break on the end of a word
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print each sentence in each line, without `<br>`

```
<p style="font-family:courier;white-space: pre;">
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
</p>
```

For example check jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/muthupandiant/sgp8rjfs/

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try with `word-wrap` 

     #id
         { 
           word-wrap: break-word ;/*Allows unbreakable words to be broken*/
         } 

     #id
        { 
          word-wrap: normal ;/*Break words only at allowed break points*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The real question is: why on Earth would you want to use *&nbsp;* in your case?

That's 6 bytes instead of 1 byte for each space!

Besides the waste of storage- and filesize, search engines will have a ball trying to understand it.

I would opt-out of whatever reason you have to use *&nbsp;* and opt-in for plain and simple space (" "), for both SEO and - even more important - less wasted space. This way you'll be achieving the same goal but delivering smaller downloads to website visitors.